# How can I use the setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
if (this.props.showFiltersHeader) {
            const { tipoBusqueda } = this.props;
            if (tipoBusqueda === '1')
                this.setState({ filterFacturaNieType: 'N'});
            else if (tipoBusqueda === '2')
                this.setState({ filterFacturaNieType: 'F'});            
            return <div>
                <div className="search-container">
                    <p>Buscar por NIE o Factura</p>
                    <div className="caja-select">
                        <select onChange={this.onChangeSelect} name="filterFacturaNieType" value={this.state.filterFacturaNieType}>
                        <option value='N'>NIE</option>
                        <option value='F'>Factura</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <span className="alert-span">{this.state.errors["filterFacturaNieType"]}</span>
                </div>
....
}
```

why don't you use the setState ?, always take the first option of the select

Comment: You're going to need to clarify a bit more. Are these calls even tripped?

Comment: yes, it enters the conditional, but the setState does nothing

Comment: Maybe it does something, but not on the object you expected it to. This is where setting a breakpoint helps a *lot*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to define a default value to your state based on the value of `tipoBusqueda`, you could do it in a `useEffect`, a componentDidMount or even in the class constructor. Since you are using a class component, this should do the trick:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setDefaultValue()
}


setDefaultValue() {
  const { tipoBusqueda } = this.props;

  if (tipoBusqueda === '1')
    this.setState({ filterFacturaNieType: 'N' });
  else if (tipoBusqueda === '2')
    this.setState({ filterFacturaNieType: 'F' });  
}
```

You shouldn't do it inside your `render` method because you will cause an infinite loop. Your setState will do your render method be called again and then you will call setState again.

The componentDidMount will be executed only once after the component mount, and never more. Since React 16.8, you can use hooks in a functional component to have state, so I would recommend you to change your class component to a functional one. You can do it this way:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Component = ({ tipoBusqueda, showFiltersHeader }) => {
  const [filterFacturaNieType, setFilterFacturaNieType] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (tipoBusqueda === '1')
      setFilterFacturaNieType('N');
    else if (tipoBusqueda === '2')
      setFilterFacturaNieType('F');
  }, [])

  if (showFiltersHeader) {
    return (
      <div className="search-container">
        <p>Buscar por NIE o Factura</p>
        <div className="caja-select">
          <select onChange={e => setFilterFacturaNieType(e.target.value)} name="filterFacturaNieType" value={filterFacturaNieType}>
            <option value='N'>NIE</option>
            <option value='F'>Factura</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return null
}

export default Component
```

You can even map the number to the letter, so you can avoid calling the setState unnecessarily:

```
const numberToLetter = {
  1: 'N',
  2: 'F'
}
```

and then, use it either on the constructor or the useState.

```
// in a class component
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    filterFacturaNieType: numberToLetter[props.tipoBusqueda]
  }
}

// or 

state = {
  filterFacturaNieType: numberToLetter[this.props.tipoBusqueda]
}

// or in a functional component, using the useState:
const [filterFacturaNieType, setFilterFacturaNieType] = useState(numberToLetter[tipoBusqueda])
```